# Selected item in simultaneously in two listviews

Tags: wpf, listview, triggers

I have two listViews on the page. I select Item in the first one and then in the second. The 
item that I've selected in the first getting Unselected.

How can I get to have in both of the listviews a selected item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override the ControlBrush to set the inactive highlight color.

```
 <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
```